# Flask: How to output string from Python but displayed as hyperlinks in HTML

Tags: python-3.x, url, flask

So, I'm getting the user input from a HTML textbox, and then returning some urls. But currently, when I directly return the URLS (in string), the HTML urls output aren't clickable; they're in just plaintext. Is there a way to convert the returned python strings to HTML urls?

I can change the format of the returned urls on the python side to anything that can be converted to HTML urls that's clickable.

Python code:

```
#this gets the query and then returns urls
@app.route('/output', methods=['POST'])
def output():
    query_list = request.form['query']
    outputResults = someFunction(query_list)
    return render_template("output.html", output=outputResults)
```

HTML code:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron text-left">
  <body>
    <style> p {white-space: pre-wrap; }</style>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    <p> {{output}}
    </p>
  </body>

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks

Comment: if your output is link like `http://www.something.com`, you should add anchor tag to your template e.g:

`<a href="{{output}}">link title</a>`

Comment: @dhentris what if I have a list of unknown quantity of links to be outputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple links in your query use for loop in your template like this:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron text-left">
  <body>
    <style> p {white-space: pre-wrap; }</style>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    {% for link in output %}
     <a href ="{{link}}">title_your_link</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```